# Increase mongodb value by %

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm learning MongoDB and NodeJs. How to correctly increase weight by 2% stored in DB when making a query without writing new value in DB with NodeJS. Something like that:

```
    const cargoQuery = Cargo.aggregate([
      {
    **IncreasedWeight**: {$multiply:[weight,{$divide:[2,100]}]}
    .../*and then use this IncreasedWeight elsewhere*/
$match: {
      $or: [
        {cargoType: {$eq: req.query.cRuleADR}, IcreasedWeight: {$lte: req.query.cRuleMaxWeight}}
      ],
      height: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleHeight},
      width: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleWidth},
      clength: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleLength}
```

Here is my doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("608c5e77291d492820c6b346"),
    "cargoType" : "palletized",
    "description" : "fdsfdsfs",
    "price" : 700,
    "height" : 2,
    "width" : 2,
    "clength" : 2,
    "weight" : 8000,
    "date" : ISODate("2021-04-30T19:45:59.000Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("60868c31caafe530e7e2d04a"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate a percentage by equation in your client language, like `(2 / 100) + 1` = `1.02`,

- `$expr` match expression condition when for internal field operation
- use `$and` and condition to construct a condition

```
const cargoQuery = Cargo.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            { cargoType: req.query.cRuleADR },
            {
              $expr: {
                $lte: [{ $multiply: ["$weight", 1.02] }, req.query.cRuleMaxWeight]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          height: { $lte: +req.query.tRuleHeight },
          width: { $lte: +req.query.tRuleWidth },
          clength: { $lte: +req.query.tRuleLength }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you @turivishal. When running the query i get Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators. It's probably not a mistake in your query but mine when doing a match $match:. Can you please post how to use that new field in match like in answer. Or I have to use pipeline? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see the update. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I don't have to update weight field in DB. I just have to increase weight only when doing a Cargo.aggregate query. I have to make a tolerance when doing a match. This tolarance is 2%. The weight value must stay untouched in DB. Running your aggregation query gives Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators. Thanks!